# How do I create HTML tables with data I acquired from an MS Access file using python?

Tags: python, html

I've been tasked with creating an attendance process. I'm completely new to this. I've managed to use the pyodbc library to acquire specific data from an .mdb file. How do I display this data in a HTML page in the form of a table using python? I have no clue where to start. Is there a library that would make this easier? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.firt you convert the data into csv file then run the code

```
def csv_to_html_table(fname,headers=None,delimiter=","):
    with open(fname) as f:
        content = f.readlines()
    #reading file content into list
    rows = [x.strip() for x in content]
    table = "<table>"
    #creating HTML header row if header is provided 
    if headers is not None:
        table+= "".join(["<th>"+cell+"</th>" for cell in headers.split(delimiter)])
    else:
        table+= "".join(["<th>"+cell+"</th>" for cell in rows[0].split(delimiter)])
        rows=rows[1:]
    #Converting csv to html row by row
    for row in rows:
        table+= "<tr>" + "".join(["<td>"+cell+"</td>" for cell in row.split(delimiter)]) + "</tr>" #+ "\n"
    table+="</table><br>"
    return table
```

then call the function

```
filename="Crushers.csv"
myheader='age,week,opp,ACscr,OPPscr,location'
html_table=csv_to_html_table(filename,myheader)
```

then type html_table to get the data(don't take the first ' and last ')

run this thing in jupyter note book

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1boOAbyMRfNK_E4ECxCgCccuKXc7-NCTL/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

you should ask a more specific question.
Provide some example of what you have already try and then explain where you are stuck.

You'll have a lot more answer like this.